# Can't make texture uniform variable to work in LWJGL 3

Tags: java, opengl, textures, shader, lwjgl

so I've been following a fair amount of tutorials on the internet and I tried to create my own graphics engine with OpenGL. The problem is that I can't make the texture work. I can render a square on the screen and change the color but I can't show a texture.

This is the Main Method:

```
public class Main implements Runnable{

public int HEIGHT = 400;
public int WIDTH = 400;

private boolean running;
private Thread thread;
private long window;

Level level;

public Main(){  
}

public void start(){
    running = true;
    thread = new Thread(this, "Game");
    thread.start();
}

public void stop(){
    try {
        thread.join();
        running = false;

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void init(){
    if(glfwInit() != GL_TRUE){
        System.err.println("Couldn't load the window");
        return;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GL_FALSE);

    window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Game!!", NULL, NULL);
    if(window == NULL){
        System.err.println("Couldn't create the window");
        return;
    }

    ByteBuffer vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
    glfwSetWindowPos(window, (GLFWvidmode.width(vidmode) - WIDTH) / 2, (GLFWvidmode.height(vidmode) - HEIGHT) / 2);

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwShowWindow(window);
    GLContext.createFromCurrent();

    Input input = new Input();
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, input);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    System.out.println("OpenGL: " + glGetString(GL_VERSION));

    Shader.loadAll();


    Matrix4f pr_matrix = Matrix4f.orthographic(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

    Shader.BG.setUniformMat4f("pr_matrix", pr_matrix);
    Shader.BG.setUniform1i("tex", 1);
    level = new Level();



}

public void run() {
    init();

    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double delta = 0.0;
    double ns = 1000000000.0 / 60.0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int updates = 0;
    int frames = 0;

    while (running) {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;
        if (delta >= 1.0) {
            update();
            updates++;
            delta--;
        }
        render();
        frames++;
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
            timer += 1000;
            System.out.println(updates + " ups, " + frames + " fps");
            updates = 0;
            frames = 0;
        }
        if (glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == GL_TRUE)
            running = false;
    }
}

private void update(){
    glfwPollEvents();
    if(Input.isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE)){
        running = false;
    }
}

private void render(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    int error = glGetError();
    if (error != GL_NO_ERROR)
        System.out.println(error);

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    level.render();

}

public static void main(String arg[]){
    new Main().start();
}
```

}

This is the Level Method:

```
public class Level {

private VertexArray background;
private Texture bgTexture;

public Level() {

    float[] vertices = new float[] { 
            -0.5f, 0.5f, 0f, 
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0f, 
            0.5f, -0.5f, 0f, 
            0.5f, 0.5f, 0f

    };

    byte[] indices = new byte[] { 0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2 };

    float[] tcs = new float[] { 
            0f, 0f, 
            0, 1.0f, 
            1.0f, 1.0f, 
            1.0f, 0 
    };

    background = new VertexArray(vertices, indices, tcs);
    bgTexture = new Texture("res/bird.png");

}

public void render() {
    Shader.BG.enable();
    bgTexture.bind();
    background.bind();

    background.draw();

    bgTexture.unbind();
    Shader.BG.disable();
}
```

Here the Texture Class:

```
public class Texture {

private int width, height;
private int texture;

public Texture(String path) {
    texture = load(path);
}

private int load(String path) {
    int[] pixels = null;
    try {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream(path));
        width = image.getWidth();
        height = image.getHeight();
        pixels = new int[width * height];
        image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, pixels, 0, width);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int[] data = new int[width * height];
    for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++) {
        int a = (pixels[i] & 0xff000000) >> 24;
        int r = (pixels[i] & 0xff0000) >> 16;
        int g = (pixels[i] & 0xff00) >> 8;
        int b = (pixels[i] & 0xff);

        data[i] = a << 24 | b << 16 | g << 8 | r;
    }

    int result = glGenTextures();
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, result);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(data));
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    return result;
}

public void bind() {
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
}

public void unbind() {
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

}

Here the Vertex Class:

```
public class VertexArray {

private int vao, vbo, ibo, tbo;
private int count;

public VertexArray(int count) {
    this.count = count;
    vao = glGenVertexArrays();
}

public VertexArray(float[] vertices, byte[] indices, float[] textureCoordinates) {
    count = indices.length;

    vao = glGenVertexArrays();
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    vbo = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertices), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(Shader.VERTEX_ATTRIB, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(Shader.VERTEX_ATTRIB);

    tbo = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(textureCoordinates), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(Shader.TCOORD_ATTRIB, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(Shader.TCOORD_ATTRIB);

    ibo = glGenBuffers();
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(indices), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

public void bind() {
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    if (ibo > 0)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
}

public void unbind() {
    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    if (ibo > 0)
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

public void draw() {
    if (ibo > 0)
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, count, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    else
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, count);
}

public void render() {
    bind();
    draw();
}
```

}

And here the Shaders:

Vertex:

```
#version 400 core

in vec4 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 tc;

uniform mat4 pr_matrix;

out vec2 tc_vr;


void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = pr_matrix * position;
    tc_vr = tc;
}
```

Fragment:

```
#version 400 core

out vec4 color;

in vec2 tc_vr;

uniform sampler2D tex;

void main(void)
{
    color = texture(tex, tc_vr);

}
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: You're setting your `tex` uniform to 1, which means that you use texture unit 1. But I don't see anything binding the texture to texture unit 1. You could try setting the uniform to 0 instead, which is the default texture unit.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Thanks a lot! It fixed the problem, I didn't realized that I wasn't declaring the texture unit anywhere.